# Bitcoin: How does Proof of Work and single transactions align?

Tags: proof-of-work, confirmations

I'm reading papers since hours and still don't get one thing:
A bitcoin transaction is an information like "Bob sends 2 BTC to Alice". This message is signed with Bobs private key and needs to be added to the blockchain that is distributed to every participant. I also got that you need to calculate a Proof of Work to be able to add something to the chain. Or in other words: The other participants won't accept your block without the proof of work.

How does Bob get this proof of work or how does Bobs message went to a person who has such I proof? I can't believe that every person making a transaction needs to calculate it's own proof. Is it really like that? If not: How does Bobs "message" is transmitted to a person who owns such a proof, how can the person make sure that Bobs message is a valid transaction (and not only garbage) and what the motivation for this person to process Bobs message at all?

Answer (score 3):

> How does Bob get this proof of work or how does Bobs message went to a person who has such I proof?

Bob offers a fee to whoever attaches his transaction to a block with the necessary proof of work. Now Bob wants to get his transaction to someone who can attach it and people who generate proof of work want Bob's transaction so they can get the fee.

When two people each want to communicate with each other, there is no difficulty in arranging that communication. We have the Internet.

> I can't believe that every person making a transaction needs to calculate it's own proof. Is it really like that?

No. Those who want to execute transactions offer a fee to those who calculate proof of work. This is a mutually beneficial arrangement.

> If not: How does Bobs "message" is transmitted to a person who owns such a proof,

Over the Internet.

> how can the person make sure that Bobs message is a valid transaction (and not only garbage)

They just check to make sure whether it follows all the rules, which everyone knows. If so, it's valid. If not, it's invalid.

> and what the motivation for this person to process Bobs message at all?

They want to make as much money as possible for the proof of work they provide. So they actively search for the transactions that offer the highest fees to them.

Answer (score -3):

As a rough quick answer for any Blockchain not just Bitcoin..

-users authenticate their transactions with Cryptographic signatures, and submit a transaction Fee

-Transactions reside in the mining pool for miners to select usually thru an auction where fees r considered like bids, the auction format may differ from one Blockchain to another

-Miners verify the signatures of TXs upon selection, and collect the fees+block reward if the block was approved.

Here's a few diagrams from my early days in cryptocurrency, can't remember the source video

[image]
[image][image]
[image]

Ps

- The word "Encrypting" in the images is not quite accurate, what is done is digitally signing using a public-private key Encryption Algorithm (elliptic curve in Bitcoin & many cryptocurrencies)
  -Transactions remain publicly readable to the miners in the mining pool (unless something called "commit-then-reveal" scheme is used to deliberately hide the content of a TX from the miners thru encryption)
- Checking the authenticity means verifying the correctness of the digital signature

The source of the figs
https://youtu.be/E2JRnFgrztM
( with only the clarifying red & blue text added by me after the comments)
It was like my first let's get an idea and see if it worth further study & research

Comment: This series of graphics is incorrect and misleading in several ways: 1. Bitcoin transactions are not encrypted. In fact the Bitcoin protocol does not use encryption anywhere at all. Transactions have cryptographic signatures, which authenticates their content as being issued by the private key holder, and protects them from being changed.

Comment: 2. Miners don't "verify the authenticity of sender and receiver". All nodes (of which miners are a subset) verify that the transaction is well-formed and valid. The signatures in the inputs attest to the owner of the funds having signed off, the only check for the receiver is whether the output script is valid.

Comment: 3. "The transaction would show that bitcoins are reduced from one wallet, and added to another." ⇒ Wallets don't exist as a construct in the Bitcoin protocol. A transaction consumes and creates Unspent Transaction Outputs.

Comment: 4. Not sure what the last slide has to do with the topic. It seems to reference the oracle problem.

Comment: Anyway, the text in your answer is much better than the graphics which are not just oversimplified but wrong. I suggest removing the images.

Comment: Cryptographic signatures r performed thru elliptic curve cryptography which is a public key Encryption scheme. Authentication is defined as the process of verifying the identity, checking the correctness of the digital signature is one way to do that; ie just different terminologies for the same thing. You r right about the last blockdiagram, It's irrelevant & I removed it

Comment: No, while they're both applications of cryptography, signing and encrypting are two orthogonal concepts. The purpose of signing is to produce a zero-knowledge attestation that the signatory holds the private key and to protect against malleation of the message. The purpose of encryption is to prevent anyone but the intended recipient from reading a message. Bitcoin transactions are unencrypted and public information, but immutable due to the signatures.

Comment: Signing and encryption **in RSA** use the same algorithm with different inputs, which is the exception rather than the rule. Bitcoin does not use RSA, it uses ECDSA. ECDSA has nothing to do with encryption, it is only a signature scheme.

Comment: Elliptic Curve Cryptography follows the same "exception" as u call it RSA follows, all public-private key Encryption Algorithms have this feature of being used interchangeably for encryption & signature, beside I did added a remark to the main answer that the use of the word Encryption in the Figs is not quite accurate

Comment: That's not correct, @ShAr. The ECDSA algorithm cannot be used for encryption at all, it is purely a signing algorithm. There exist EC-based encryption algorithms, but they are unrelated to ECDSA. The fact that signing and encrypting are duals of eachother is unique to RSA (where signing is "encrypting with the private key and decrypting with the public", approximately).

Comment: ECC is a mathematical equation taken on its own, but ECDSA is the algorithm that is applied to ECC to make it appropriate for security encryption. https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/diffie-hellman-rsa-dsa-ecc-and-ecdsa-asymmetric-key-algorithms,  "Cryptography (ECC) is a key-based technique for encrypting data" https://avinetworks.com/glossary/elliptic-curve-cryptography/

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong. ECDSA does not do encryption. I am not going to argue further.

Comment: "The ECDSA algorithm can't be used for encryption. It's not that there's no accepted way to do it, it's that it's simply not possible to do so." —https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24520/8801

Comment: Both of u, I wonder why wasn't u that "enthusiased" to discuss the UTXOs lifespan Q that u voted to close & like chasing me( not a certain topic, like I pursue the frobiden UTXOs question) in every answer???

Comment: @ShAr: I'm not chasing you, a user flagged this post as "very low quality", so I took a look. After reading, I provided feedback about deficiencies in the content of your post to give you a chance to improve it. When my feedback wasn't convincing to you, I provided further evidence. My goals are two-fold: I am trying to improve the quality of posts on this site (as I have for eight years), and I'm trying to help people to contribute better in the future.--It is my impression that my approach is not working for you. How would you like me to provide guidance next time?